# jQuery - How to get an element's class from ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I'm loading my website's pages with ajax by replacing the content inside the `main` tag. 
Problem is, using Wordpress, each page has its own `body` classes that are useful for styling purposes, so I want to replace the old page's body classes by the next page's classes. 
I thought i'd run a new ajax request to get the whole html page, then check for the `body` element, then use `.attr("class")` to get the list of class and finally replace the old body classes by the new one...
But the classes always return `undefined` instead of a list of classes.
**EDIT**: I tried to use `.cd-main-content` instead of body and weirdly it works, I get the classes of this element. So I assume now that the problem doesn't come from my syntax but from the element itself.
How can I possibly get it to work on the `body` element ? (I already tried to replace `.find` by `.filter` but it doesn't work either.)

**HTML stucture**

```
<body id="body" class="home page-id-number other-classes">
    <main>
        <div class="cd-main-content">
            <!-- inside is the dynamically loaded content-->
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({url: url, 
    success: function(data){
        var body = $(data).find("#body"); 
        var classes = body.attr("class");
        console.log(data); //returns the html as expected
        console.log("body : "+body); //returns [object Object]
        console.log("classes : "+classes); //returns undefined
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"body" tag filtering by jQuery when getting from string.

So $(data)[0] will back all content, without body.

Also use filter, not "find"
So you can get classes like that:

```
$.ajax({url: url, 
    success: function(data){
       //replace body tag
       data = data.replace("<body", "<container").replace("body>", "container>");
       var classes = $(data).filter("container").attr("class");
        $("body").attr("class", classes);
    } 
});
```

Comment: Oh, replacing the body tag is a good idea. 
I actually prefer your solution to mine, because it doesn't require to modify the html. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Your jQuery code is wrong:

```
$.ajax({url: url, 
    success: function(data){
        var body = $(data).find("body"); //not #body
        var classes = body.attr("class");
        console.log(data); //returns the html as expected
        console.log("body : "+body); //returns [object Object]
        console.log("classes : "+classes); //returns undefined
    } 
});
```

The right selector is `body` not `#body`, which is an id selector

So, to change your body classes use this code:

```
$.ajax({url: url, 
    success: function(data){
        var classes = $(data).find("body").attr("class"); //get the classes
        $("body").attr("class", classes); //set the classes
    } 
});
```

[jQuery Selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my code to avoid confusion. My body does have an id of body, so this is not where the problem comes from.
Thanks for the tips to set the classes !

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it's not ideal but it fixed the problem.

First, I have to assume that it is not possible to get the attributes of the body element as it appears to be filtered by jQuery. However it is possible to get the child elements.

I ended up adding the body classes to both the `body` and `main` elements (in the header.php file of wordpress).

Here's my code now :

**HTML**

```
<body id="body" class="home page-id-number other-classes">
    <main class="home page-id-number other-classes">
    <!-- if I had the possibility, I'd have added "data-body-class" instead of "class" -->
        <div class="cd-main-content">
            <!-- inside is the dynamically loaded content-->
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

**jQuery**

```
$.ajax({url: url, 
    success: function(data){
        var classes = $(data).filter("main").attr("class"); //get the classes 
        $("body, main").attr("class", classes); //set the classes 
    } 
});
```